# Get value from nested arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have data that is structured like the following:

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Biomes',
    icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',
    isParent: true,
    children: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Redwood forest',
        icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr'
    }]
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Trees',
    icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
    children: [{
        id: 8,
        name: 'Redwood',
        icon: 'mdi-pine-tree'
    }]
}];
```

The top level is an array of objects, and each object can have a child field `children` which itself can be an array of objects. If I know the value of `id`, how can I find the object (or more importantly the object name), based on that id value?

Comment: Will the id match a object in the parents and children or just the parents?

Comment: @bassxzero it will match one or the other. It could match any parent or any child object.

Comment: Does the nesting will be only one level or it can go deeper?

Comment: There can be multiple children with same Id?

Comment: For now just one level but I would prefer a solution that is extensible to N levels deep

Comment: IDs are totally unique per object

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion here to get the object no matter how deep it is. I've filtered out the object. It will only give the object without `children` property. You can include it in the way you want

```
function getObjectFromId(arr, id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i].id === id) {
     // return arr[i]   // If you want full object with children
      const { children, ...rest } = arr[i];
      return rest;
    }
    if (arr[i].children) {
      const result = getObjectFromId(arr[i].children, id);
      if (result) return result;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "Biomes",
    icon: "mdi-image-filter-hdr",
    isParent: true,
    children: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Redwood forest",
        icon: "mdi-image-filter-hdr",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Trees",
    icon: "mdi-pine-tree",
    children: [
      {
        id: 8,
        name: "Redwood",
        icon: "mdi-pine-tree",
        children: [
          {
            id: 9,
            name: "Redwood",
            icon: "mdi-pine-tree",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

function getObjectFromId(arr, id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i].id === id) {
      // return arr[i]   // If you want full object with children
      const { children, ...rest } = arr[i];
      return rest;
    }
    if (arr[i].children) {
      const result = getObjectFromId(arr[i].children, id);
      if (result) return result;
    }
  }
}

console.log(getObjectFromId(arr, 1));
console.log(getObjectFromId(arr, 8));
console.log(getObjectFromId(arr, 9));
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Biomes',
    icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',
    isParent: true,
    children: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Redwood forest',
        icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr'
    }]
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Trees',
    icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
    children: [{
        id: 0,
        name: 'whatever',
        icon: 'new-tree'
    },{
        id: 8,
        name: 'Redwood',
        icon: 'mdi-pine-tree'
    }]
}];

const findById = (id) => arr
    .filter(x => x.id === id || x.children.some(child => id === child.id))
    .map(y => ({...y, children: y.children.filter(child => id === child.id)}))

console.log(findById(0))
```

You can first `filter` out all parents who has the same `id` or if the parent has child with same id via `some`, which then using `map` to and `filter` to remove all children who don't have the `id`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** 2 for loop.

```js
const inputArray = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Biomes',
    icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',
    isParent: true,
    children: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Redwood forest",
      icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Trees',
    icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
    children: [{
      id: 8,
      name: "Redwood",
      icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
    }]
  }
];

console.log(findById(8));

function findById(id) {
  for (const parent of inputArray) {
    if (parent.id === id)
      return parent;     
    for (const child of parent.children)
      if (child.id === id)
        return child;
  }
  return null;
}
```

**Solution 2:** multiple nested level:

```js
const inputArray = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Biomes',
    icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',
    isParent: true,
    children: [{
      id: 1,
      name: "Redwood forest",
      icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr'
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Trees',
    icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
    children: [{
      id: 8,
      name: "Redwood",
      icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
      children: [{
        id: 12,
        name: "Test Level 2",
        icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
        children: [{
          id: 13,
          name: "Test Level 3",
          icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
];

console.log(findById(13, inputArray));

function findById(id, array) {
  for (const parent of array) {
    if (parent.id === id)
      return parent;

    if ('children' in parent) {
      const result = findById(id, parent.children);
      if (result) return result;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: This is indeed the perfect solution for only single level of nesting but won't work if it will go deeper? *For now just one level but I would prefer a solution that is extensible to N levels deep*

Comment: @decpk I added both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First arg for child

Second arg for main

```js
const arr = [
    {id: 0,name: 'Biomes',icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',isParent: true,
    children: [{id: 1,name: 'Redwood forest',icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',},],},
    {id: 2,name: 'Trees',icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
    children: [{id: 8,name: 'Redwood',icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',},],},
];

const getChildById = (_id, _id2 = false)=>{
    for(const main of arr){
        if(_id2 !== false && main.id !== _id2)continue;
        for(const child of main.children){
            if(child.id === _id)return child;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

(async()=>{
    const i_want_this_id = 8;

    //

    const a = getChildById(i_want_this_id);
    console.log('Found', a);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using `Array find()` method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

```
let object= arr.find((item)=>item.id === "your ID");
console.log(object?.name);
```

```js
const arr = [{
    id: 0,
    name: 'Biomes',
    icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',
    isParent: true,
    children: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Redwood forest',
        icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr'
    }]
},{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Trees',
    icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
    children: [{
        id: 8,
        name: 'Redwood',
        icon: 'mdi-pine-tree'
    }]
}];

let object= arr.find((item)=>item.id === 2);
console.log(object?.name);
```

```
let object= arr.find((item)=>item.id === "your ID");
console.log(object?.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To find at parent and child level

```js
const arr=[{id:0,name:'Biomes',icon:'mdi-image-filter-hdr',isParent:!0,children:[{id:1,name:"Redwood forest",icon:'mdi-image-filter-hdr'}]},{id:2,name:'Trees',icon:'mdi-pine-tree',children:[{id:8,name:"Redwood",icon:'mdi-pine-tree',}]}]

const res = arr.reduce((a,item)=>{
    const { children, ...i} = item; 
    a.push(...children, i);
    return a; 
},[]);

function findInData(id){
  return res.find(o=>o.id===id);
}

console.log(findInData(8)?.name);
console.log(findInData(2)?.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findChildrenById(data, cid) {
  for (let p = 0; p < data.length; p += 1) {
    if (data[p].id === cid) return data[p].name
    let res = data[p].children.find(c => c.id === cid)
    if (res) return res.name
  }

  return null
}


const arr = [{
  id: 0,
  name: 'Biomes',
  icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr',
  isParent: true,
  children: [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Redwood forest',
    icon: 'mdi-image-filter-hdr'
  }]
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Trees',
  icon: 'mdi-pine-tree',
  children: [{
    id: 8,
    name: 'Redwood',
    icon: 'mdi-pine-tree'
  }]
}];

console.log(findChildrenById(arr, 2))
```